# Create a new div and display it where the mouse cursor is on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment, the circles are being appended to `<p>` in the html markup.
You can see how I have done this below.

But what I actually want is for the div to be created where the mouse cursor is the on the page.
How might I get the position of the cursor and create a div there?

Thanks.

```
var count = 0;
/*
 * Function(makeLetters)
 * Removes first character in text box.
 * Creates circle Letters using first character.
 */
$(document).click(function (makeLetters) {
    //Get characters currently entered into textbox
    var letters = $('#letters').val();
    //Take the firstLetter only
    var firstLetter = letters.substr(0, 1);
    //Count how many characters currently entered
    var numberOfLetters = letters.length;
    //Use length of entry to take all characters except first
    var restOfLetters = letters.substr(1, numberOfLetters);
    //All characters except first set as textbox entry
    $("#letters").val(restOfLetters);
    //Check that there is a first character
    if (firstLetter != "") {
        count++;
        //Create a new circle letter by inserting new div class
        $("p").append('<div class="circle' + count + '" style="border-radius: 50%;width:    36px;height:36px;padding:8px;background:#FF7D5C;color:black;text-align:center;font:32px Arial, sans-serif;display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;margin-bottom:4px;">' + firstLetter.toUpperCase() + '</div>');
        $("p").children().last().hide().fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cant get the mouse position on its own, but you could use jQuery to  listen to the `mousemove` event and store the position in a variable for use later like so:

```
var mousePosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mousePosition.x = e.pageX;
    mousePosition.y = e.pageY;
});
```

Then you would need to use `postion: [absolute/fixed];` to position the div based on the `mousePosition`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do that by getting the mouse position from the event, that you for some strange reason named `makeLetters` ?

```
$(document).click(function(event) {

    var letters         = $('#letters').val();
    var firstLetter     = letters.substr(0, 1);
    var numberOfLetters = letters.length;
    var restOfLetters   = letters.substr(1, numberOfLetters);
    var mouseLeft       = event.pageX;
    var mouseTop        = event.pageY;

    $("#letters").val(restOfLetters);

    if (firstLetter != "") {
        count++;

        var div = $('<div />', {
            'class' : 'circle' + count,
            text  : firstLetter.toUpperCase(),
            css : {
                 position: 'fixed',
                 top     : mouseTop + 'px',
                 left    : mouseLeft + 'px', 
                 display : 'none'
                 // ... the rest of the styles here

            }
        });

        $("p").append( div.fadeIn() );
    }
});
```